# Angular How to set all links to a different color on RouterLinkActive

Tags: angular, typescript, sass

I have a navbar and I want all the links to be black when I navigate to the About Page, however, my SCSS statement doesn't seem to work on all the anchor-tags.

html

```
 <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" [routerLink] = "['/home']">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" [routerLink] = "['/about']" routerLinkActive = "BlackLinks">About</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
    </div>
```

SCSS

```
.BlackLinks{
  a{
    color: #343434 !important
  }
}
```

I think I could achieve this with ngClass but I feel then I would require to make a variable in service and set it when I change to a new page, but I don't want to do that.

Comment: Did not get you ? Is that you want an active color for the currently active link ?

Comment: @Jithin B Sorry about that engrish, I edited to hopefully make more sense

Comment: Ok. You want the links to be black when you are in about page. What is the default color of nav-link ?

Comment: Yes that is correct and the default color is white

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a class to each nav-link, when you are in the about page. Consider the class to be color-black, then

```
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" [ngClass]="{ 'color-black': about.isActive }">Current Page</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" [ngClass]="{ 'color-black': about.isActive }">About</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" [ngClass]="{ 'color-black': about.isActive }">Gallery</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" [ngClass]="{ 'color-black': about.isActive }">Contact</a>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.nav-link {
   color: #ffffff;
}

.nav-link.color-black {
    color: #000000;
 }
```

I have just given the logic for adding the class color-black. You can use your own way to add a class while you are in about page. There are different methods to add a class when you are in a particular page.

Comment: Yes but as I stated dont want to do this with NgClass I wanted to do this with routerLinkActive, but I dont know if its possible or not

Comment: Are you able to add BlackLinks class when you are in about page using your method?

Comment: No add scss to my about component page doesent affect my navbar component

Comment: What i meant was , are you able to add the class using this *routerLinkActive = "BlackLinks"* ?

Comment: Yes it works but only affects the route that I am in, e.g if I am in about then only the about is active